# Spacing issue in Latex

Tags: spacing

I have the code below as

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in,left=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\bf{F}=-\bf{\nabla}\text{V} \hspace{4cm} \text{(-ve is just an ambiguity)}
\end{equation*}
wiriting in terms of potential form we have \vspace{-2mm}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{equation*}
V=V^{ext}+V^{int} ;
\end{equation*}
\columnbreak
\begin{equation*}
F_{i}^{ext}=-\bf{\nabla}_{i} \text{$V^{ext}$}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
F_{i}^{int}=-\bf{\nabla}_{i} \text{$V^{int}$}
\end{equation*}
\end{multicols}

\vspace{-4.5mm}
where, $V^{ext}$ depends on coordinates of position of particle.
If the force between the particles hold newton law of motion,then $V^{int}$ is a function of relative distance between two interacting particles i.e. 
    \end{document}
```

I see that where I have used the `multicol` and `columnbreak` command there is enough spacing between two, which I don't want. Also, this is too lengthy to write text left side and some comment on right side (even if the text is too large or I want to write below it on right hand side.)

Comment: Off-topic: `\bf` is a switch, i.e., it does not take an argument enclosed in curly braces. To limit the scope of `\bf`, you must write `{\bf F}...`, *not* `\bf{F}...`. That said, `\bf` is a Plain-TeX command; there are better alternatives for LaTeX document. E.g., `\mathbf{F}` and `\boldsymbol{\nabla}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `\bf` has been deprecated for more than 25 years in LaTeX.

I fixed several input errors, you should check the differences in order to write better code.

There's no need to use `multicol`; use a nested `aligned`.

The parenthetical remark is better in line, not in the display. And *never* write “-ve” in a paper (actually, never ever).

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in,left=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

Some text before the equation
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{F}=-\bm{\nabla}V
\end{equation*}
(negative is just an ambiguity). Writing in terms of potential form we have
\begin{equation*}
V=V^{\mathrm{ext}}+V^{\mathrm{int}},
\qquad\qquad
\begin{aligned}[t]
F_{i}^{\mathrm{ext}} &= -\bm{\nabla}_{i} V^{\mathrm{ext}}, \\
F_{i}^{\mathrm{int}} &= -\bm{\nabla}_{i} V^{\mathrm{int}},
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $V^{\mathrm{ext}}$ depends on coordinates of position of particle.
If the force between the particles hold newton law of motion,then $V^{\mathrm{int}}$
is a function of relative distance between two interacting particles i.e. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am using `\bf` command more then 25 years and I am happy. But, of course, the usage of `\bf` command in the original question is bad:).

Comment: @wipet Please, I'm talking about LaTeX. But I added the remark

Answer (score 1):

To long for the comment ...

It is not clear what is your problem. You also have contradictory: *there is enough spacing between two, which I don't want*. So see, if the following guessing, in which is not used `multicolumn` environment,  can help you. At least in MWE below is used correct syntax in math expressions:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in,left=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}  % new
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % new

\begin{document}

    \[
\mathbf{F}=-\boldsymbol{\nabla}V 
    \]
where $V$ is just an ambiguity. Writing in terms of potential form we have 
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{2}{>{$}C<{$}}}
V=V^{\mathrm{ext}} + V^{\mathrm{int}} ;
    &   \begin{aligned}
    F_{i}^{\mathrm{ext}}  & = -\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{i} V^{\mathrm{ext}}  \\
    F_{i}^{\mathrm{int}}  & = -\boldsymbol{\nabla}_{i} V^{\mathrm{ext}}
        \end{aligned}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
where $V^{\mathrm{ext}}$ depends on coordinates of position of particle.
If the force between the particles hold Newton law of motion,then $V^{\mathrm{int}}$ is a function of relative distance between two interacting particles i.e.
    \end{document}
```

[image]