# Syntax errors in a 'tabularx' environment

Tags: math-mode, tabularx

I am having some issue where Ii am unable to figure out whata is the error in my latex file and I am using TexStudio.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tabularx}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{2}{>{$}C<{$}}}
    {\bf E $\to$ -E} \hspace{0.3cm} \text{and} \hspace{0.3cm} {\bf B $\to$ -B} \hspace{0.5cm} \text{where we have,} \hspace{0.5mm}
        &   \begin{aligned}
            {\bf $\nabla$.E}  & = $\frac{\rho}{\epsilon}$\hspace{0.5mm},  \\
            {\bf $\nabla$ $\cross$ E}  & = -$\dfrac{B}{dt}$\hspace{0.5mm}.
        \end{aligned}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us how the `C` column type is defined.

Comment: The `aligned` block is within a math column.  Once inside an `aligned` block, everything is already in math mode, so any `$` sign within that scope is an error (unless within an explicit `\text` string).  There are multiple `$` signs within your `aligned` block; all of them are incorrect.  Furthermore, `\bf` is not proper LaTeX notation, and it's unclear what should be bold.  It would be a good idea for you to read the `amsmath` users guide (`texdoc amsldoc`).

Comment: @Mico i had this issue earlier and someone fixed for me.If you can have a look on the link you might get what C is? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543102/spacing-issue-in-latex?noredirect=1#comment1371779_543102

Comment: @barbarabeeton yeah o forgot i have modified it but still having problem.can you rectify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first attempt here wasn't a final answer.  That was impossible without knowing the definition of `C` in the `tabularx` preamble.

The definition of `C` has been copied from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/546133) posted by Zarko to an earlier question.

Finally, all the `$` signs have been removed:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tabularx}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{2}{>{$}C<{$}}}
    {\bf E \to -E} \hspace{0.3cm} \text{and} \hspace{0.3cm} {\bf B \to -B} \hspace{0.5cm} \text{where we have,} \hspace{0.5mm}
        &   \begin{aligned}
            {\bf \nabla.E}  & = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon}\hspace{0.5mm},  \\
            {\bf \nabla \cross E}  & = -\dfrac{B}{dt}\hspace{0.5mm}.
        \end{aligned}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: as i checked you solution and result, there is some minimal gap in the R.H.S if you notice.can it be rectify and also about the C you are asking, i also dont know about it as iasked earlier someone and he solved it. Here is the link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/543102/spacing-issue-in-latex?noredirect=1#comment1371779_543102.